# Spring ReflectionUtils or pure Java Lang Reflection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reflection

I'm currently working on a spring project in which I have to do some very generic things. A friend just recommend me to use Spring ReflectionUtils and some existential doubts came into my mind.

What would be the difference between using ReflectionUtils and just the standard java reflection (apart from having to deal with the exceptions, it seems to me that ReflectionUtils is more boilerplate)

Here's some code to show you:

```
public Object genericObject(){
    return ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(
                  ReflectionUtils.findMethod(genericService.getClass(), "getGenericObject"),
                  genericService)
    
}
```

and the standard java way:

```
public Object genericObject() throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {

    return genericService.getClass().getMethod("getGenericObject").invoke(genericService);}
```

(I know is not the best exception handling, it's just for representation)

what you guys think? let me know!

Comment: Wouldn't the documentation of `ReflectionUtils` be the right point to find out what it does differently and why it exists in the first place?

Comment: @Holger the documentation just says: "Simple utility class for working with the reflection API and handling reflection exceptions. Only intended for internal use.". Since I am working with the reflection API, I just want to know if someone here could give me and opinion.

Comment: Then, you already have your answer. "*Only intended for internal use*" means, you should not use it.